# Map contour points to original image

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I've performed some basic image operations and managed to isolate the object I am interested in.

As a result, I ended up with a container; `get<0>(results)` holding the corresponding `(x, y)` of the object. For visual purposes, I drew these points on a different frame named `contourFrame`

My question is, how do I map these points back to the original image?

I have looked into the combination of [`findHomography()`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html?highlight=findhomography) and [`warpPerspective`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#void%20warpPerspective(InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20InputArray%20M,%20Size%20dsize,%20int%20flags,%20int%20borderMode,%20const%20Scalar&%20borderValue)) but in order to find the homography matrix, I need to provide respective destination points which is what I am looking for in the first place.

[`remap()`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/remap/remap.html) seems to do what I am looking for but I think its a misunderstanding of the API on my part but after trying it out, it returns a blank white frame.

Is `remap()` even the way to go about this? If yes, how? If no, what other method can I use to map my contour points to another image?

A Python solution/suggestion works with me as well.

**Edit I**

For the current scenario, its a 1-1 mapping back to the original image. But what if I rotate the original image? Or move my camera back and forth i.e. move it closer and further away? How can I still map back the coordinates to the newly oriented original image?

**Original Image**

[image: iPad]

**Results**

[image: Results]

**Top Left:** Canny Edge
**Top Right:** Dilated
**Bottom Left:** Eroded
**Bottom Right:** Frame with desired object/contour

```
tuple<vector<vector<Point>>, Mat, Mat> removeStupidIcons(Mat& edges)
{
    Mat dilated, eroded;
    vector<vector<Point>> contours, filteredContours;

    dilate(edges, dilated, Mat(), Point(-1, -1), 5);
    erode(dilated, eroded, Mat(), Point(-1, -1), 5);

    findContours(eroded, contours, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    for(vector<Point>contour: contours)
        if(contourArea(contour) < 200)
            filteredContours.push_back(contour);

    return make_tuple(filteredContours, dilated, eroded);
}

Mat mapPoints(Mat& origin, Mat& destination)
{
    Mat remapWindow, mapX, mapY;

    mapX.create(origin.size(), CV_32FC1);
    mapY.create(origin.size(), CV_32FC1);

    remap(origin, destination, mapX, mapY, CV_INTER_LINEAR);

    return destination;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    string image_path = "ipad.jpg";

    original = imread(image_path);

    blur(original, originalBlur, Size(15, 15));
    cvtColor(originalBlur, originalGrey, CV_RGB2GRAY);

    Canny(originalGrey, cannyEdges, 50, 130, 3);
    cannyEdges.convertTo(cannyFrame, CV_8U);

    tuple<vector<vector<Point>>, Mat, Mat> results = removeStupidIcons(cannyEdges);
//  
//  get<0>(results) -> contours
//  get<1>(results) -> matrix after dilation
//  get<2>(results) -> matrix after erosion

    Mat contourFrame = Mat::zeros(original.size(), CV_8UC3);

    Scalar colour = Scalar(rand()&255, rand()&255, rand()&255);

    drawContours(contourFrame, get<0>(results), -1, colour, 3);

    Mat contourCopy, originalCopy;

    original.copyTo(originalCopy); contourFrame.copyTo(contourCopy);

    // a white background is returned.
    Mat mappedFrame = mapPoints(originalCopy, contourCopy);

    imshow("Canny", cannyFrame);
    imshow("Original", original);
    imshow("Contour", contourFrame);
    imshow("Eroded", get<2>(results));
    imshow("Dilated", get<1>(results));
    imshow("Original Grey", originalGrey);
    imshow("Mapping Result", contourCopy);

    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm mobile so can't be more helpful but none of those methods you mentioned do *anything* like what you're looking for, this is much more simple. You can simply loop through your result image and find the locations of non-zero entries for starters...

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Do you need the coordinates of the icon of your interest? Haven't you just calculated them on your bottom-right image? What mapping exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Yes, I have calculated them in the bottom right image. For the above case, its a 1-1 mapping back to the original image. But what if I rotate the original image? Or move my camera back and forth I.e. move it closer and further away? Without performing all of these morphological  operations again; I know they're not as expensive but for learning purposes, how can I still map back the coordinates to the newly oriented original image?

Comment: @eshirima So, say you have a distorted picture of an iPad (taken from some angle, some distance etc), and you detect some point of your interest on the iPad. And now you need to undistort the iPad so that it looks flat and rectangular, and to map the detected point accordingly? Is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: @kazarey In a nutshell, yes..